# Powershell Reverse Escape Character

Tags: powershell, escaping

I need to know if there is a way to expand a PowerShell variable, and simultaneously not remove the next character.

What I have is the command:

```
"iCacls $Destination /GRANT domain\$userN:(OI)(CI)(M) /t" | Invoke-NativeExpression
```

Where the function Invoke-NativeExpression looks like:

```
    function Invoke-NativeExpression
{
    param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0)]
   [string]$Expression
    )

    process
    {
        $executable,$arguments = $expression -split ' '
        $arguments = $arguments | foreach {"'$_'"}
        $arguments = $arguments -join ' '
        $command = $executable + ' ' + $arguments

      if ($command)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Invoking '$command'"
            Invoke-Expression -command $command
        }
    }
}
```

This method works great for non variable groups, for example `domain\Admins:perms` is fine.

Is there a way to allow PowerShell to accept $UserN: without seeing :(OI)(CI) as part of the variable name? A sort of reverse reverse escape character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{}` around the name like so:

```
"${UserN}:(OI)(CI)(M)"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, unfortunately I found another "hack" and used that.

I like yours and @mjolinor 's approach and marked them up. But since I used my hack as my solution I will mark that the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of different ways to solve this:

Subexpressions:

```
"iCacls $Destination /GRANT domain\$($userN):(OI)(CI)(M) /t"
```

Format string:

```
'iCacls $Destination /GRANT domain\{0}:(OI)(CI)(M) /t' -f $UserN
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea to hack it, and worked right after I posted this. Figures!

What I did was:

```
$uUserN = ":(OI)(CI)(M) /t"
"iCacls $Destination /GRANT domain\$userN$uUserN" | Invoke-NativeExpression
```

Is it especially pretty or readible, probably not. It did work though!

Comment: Sure, back to back variables will work because `$` is not a valid character for a variable name.  That said, the prescribed way to delineate a variable name from the surrounding text is to use `{}` around the optional scope & name part of the variable.

Comment: Yes. And once I saw your solutions it came back to me... Seems silly I danced around it all morning, I blame it on all the other challenges of these new updated scripts I have been working on! Regardless. After thinking about I like your solution better and I am goin to accept it.